# Null safety and checking for `Null`

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

this piece of code

```dart
  static fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> j) {
    return _TheCountry(
      name: j["Name"]??"",
      dialCode: j["DialCode"]??"",
      iso2Code: j["Iso2"]??"",
      englishName: j["EnglishName"]??"",
      iso3Code: j["Iso3"]??"",
      currency: j["Currency"]??"",
      capital: j["Capital"]??"",
      dialLengths: List.castFrom(getDialLengths(j["DialLength"]??"",)),
    );
  }
```

worked previously, but now the test fails by throwing,

```
Failed to load "xxx/xxxx/the_country_number_test.dart": type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

the error is thrown while accessing `j['DialCode']` ('DialCode' property might not exist),
AFAIK accessing DialCode property by `j['DialCode']` is giving me `Null` object but **how do i get away with using `j['DialCode']??""`**

Comment: please check this way : change type of DialCode From 'String' to 'var'

Comment: @Uni yes it is what i am fallowing right, `nonNullableString = nullableString ?? ""` but still nullableString here is `Null` not `null`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `contains` like this

```
j.contains("DialCode") ? j["DialCode"] : “”
```